# TeamCity and JIRA over HTTPS

Tags: https, teamcity, jira

I have JIRA and TeamCity running on two separate servers both accessible via HTTPS and self signed certificates.

I would now like to integrate JIRA as TeamCity's issue tracker.

However, when I try and setup the connection from TeamCity I get a `CertificateException`.

TeamCity is on a Ubuntu 101.10 machine and I tried to import the certificate from the JIRA server into `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/security/` but this made no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command for [importing a self-signed certificate](http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/java/keytool-cacerts-java-ssl):

```
keytool -import -alias joe -file server.crt -keystore C:/jdk1.5.0_06/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit
```

So if that doesn't work, are you sure this jdk is actually used by TeamCity?

Comment: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk is the only jdk that is installed.

Comment: @Alan: yes but TeamCity can come with its own jre bundle within the product. Did you import the certificate into *that* `jre/lib/security/cacerts` file?

Comment: still the same issue and I don't see a jre under the TeamCity directory